# How to activate special button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a button that opens a link in the same tab. Allthough I cant find where I should place the javascript to do that. Here is my code: 
https://github.com/GetThunkin/GetThunkin/blob/master/onboarding.php
And Here Is the outcome (So far)
http://getthunkin.sanderjochems.nl/github/onboarding.php

Comment: Post the relevant code here

Comment: so when I hear "open a link in the same tab", I am just thinking about a simple link on a web page, and I don't believe that is what you are trying to do because that is as simple as using the <a href="link">click me</a>

Comment: @AbdulShaikh I am trying to do that but where should I put it.

Comment: @LucaGalassi - in the HTML would be a good start

Comment: Yes but how would I define what button should do it? @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too confuse.. But i think this is what you need.. Give it a try

```
<div class="button2">
  <div class="container">   
<div class="btn">
    <a href="url"><span>View Classes</span></a>
    <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill try it out

Comment: I use the href in the span so you can use it as a link that opens on same window

Comment: This will help you as well to understand how to use the href https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: I used this and then added this:
<style type="text/css"> a {text-decoration:none;} </style>
 <style type="text/css"> a { color: inherit; } </style>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a href="https://google.ca" target="_blank">Open In New Tab</a>
```

This will open the link in a new tab

Comment: Should I add this in the div tags? Or in the head or body?

Comment: add it to the link